# Does tensorflow rely on a specific version of protobuf?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am having a problem with tensorflow (V2.3.1) and protobuf (V3.14.0). When executing a python script I get the following errors:

AttributeError: 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeCo' object has no attribute 'append'

This appears to be coming from within tensorflow, but I could be wrong.

I am using python 3.8 and ubuntu 20.04.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Peter.

Comment: Run ```pip install -U tensorflow``` may solve the problem .

Answer (score 0):

It does not always depend on the versions but sometimes due to the constant improvement and updating of both `Tensorflow` and `Protobuf` causes these conflicts.
Since you are already using latest `Protobuf` version you can upgrade to the latest `Tensorflow` version.

```
pip install -U tensorflow  

pip install -U protobuf
```

If you still have the issue, you can raise a bug in `Github`.